# For and if conditions nested in padas df

Tags: python, pandas

How can I make a take certain values of a df by iterating through a df.

I have a df like this:

```
        A   B   C
    0  10  10  35
    1  11  25  35
    2  12  40  30
    3  10  40  50
    .   .  .   .
   5000 16  12  50
```

I am trying to retrieve the values of `A` when `B is below 40` and `C is below 50`. I understand that I should try to iterate somehow like this:

```
Z = []
for i in range(0, len(df)):
     if df[(df['B'][i] < 40) & (df['C'][i] < 50)]:
        Z = df['A'][i]
```

But as this is a df I am trying to iterate through all the df like this:

```
Z = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     if df[(df['B'] < 40) & (df['C'] < 50)]:
        Z = df['A']
```

Is my approach wrong? How could I make this cleaner?

Edit: Solution

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matrix = np.random.rand(5,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['A','B','C'])


newA = df[(df['B'] >= 0.5) & (df['C'] <=0.5 )]
target = newA['A']
```

Comment: Hi, is [df.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/referenceapipandas.DataFrame.where.html) here helping?

Comment: @credenco But how?

I used:

`Z = np.where(df['B'] < 40) & (df['C'] < 50), df['A'])`

But now I get this as result `array(0.01324)`

Comment: Did the duplicate answer solve your problem?

Comment: `import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matrix = np.random.rand(5,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['A','B','C'])


newA = df[(df['B'] >= 0.5) & (df['C'] <=0.5 )]
target = newA['A']
`

This is maybe what u are looking for.